Getting a mask for a shader on the opposite side of the light source
I want to make a planet shader, where I want mask out lights only on the dark side of my object reacting to light or the sun object.
Is there a way to get a shader to react, no matter where I position the light?
I don't know how to start, so this is just my initial progress.

